# Regex: don't match string if it's between two other specified strings

Tags: python, regex, string

Suppose some text on the following format:

```latex
% Select this string

Also select the string % beyond the percentage sign

But don't select the string \% beyond the percentage sign preceded by \

\begin{example}
[some arbitrary text...]
% Don't select this string
[some arbitrary text...]
\end{example}

% Do select this string

\begin{example}
[some arbitrary text...]
% Don't select this string
[some arbitrary text...]
\end{example}
```

I want to match each string beyond `%` (including `%`), except those that are between `\begin{example}` and `\end{example}` and those that start with a percentage sign preceded by a `\`, *e.g.* `\%`.

How do I go about doing this using Python?

I got stuck with `(?<!\\)%.*`.

Comment: What programming language or tool are you using?

Comment: @sindri_baldur Python

Comment: Why should `But don't select \%` not be matched? it does not start with `\%` right? Should all the matches contain a `%` in the line? https://regex101.com/r/T11tHk/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird I want to match each string **beyond** `%` (including `%`), except those that are between `\begin{example}` and `\end{example}` and those that start with a percentage sign preceded by a \, e.g. `\%`.

Comment: @woeterb Like this? https://regex101.com/r/eMLfyY/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Like that, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a capturing group keeping what you want, which is the whole line after the percentage sign.

But first match what you don't want, which is from `\begin{example}` till `\end{example}`.

As the dot does not cross newlines, you could use `[\s\S]*?` to make it span multiple lines.

```
\\begin{example}[\s\S]*?\\end{example}|((?<!\\)%.*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9PpEau/1)

Answer (score 0):

My attempt at answering this question(I'm new to Stack Overflow and this is my first answer) is less regex-involved, but nonetheless, it works:

```
import re
def search_text(string):
    text = (text + " ").split("\n")  #split text based on newlines
    selected_lines = []  #will store strings meeting requirements
    in_answer = False   #boolean used for determining whether string is in \begin{example} and \end{example}
    for line in text:
        if line.lstrip().startswith("\begin{example}"):  #if line begins with \begin{example}, we can generally skip anything inside by changing in_example to True
            in_example = True
        elif line.lstrip().startswith("\end{example}"):
            in_example = False
        if not in_answer:
            regex = re.compile(r"[^\\]+%[^\\%]+")  #regex for substring that can be added to selected_lines
            search = regex.search(line)
            if search is None:
                continue
            else:
                selected_lines.append(search.group())
    return selected_lines
```

Just run the function on a string like this:

```
"%Select this line \n Also select the line \% beyond the percentage sign \n \begin{example} \n %Don't select this line [Some arbitrary text] \n \end{example} \n %Select me \%Nothing else"
```